# NSNumber out of scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnumber

I am having trouble figuring out why my NSNumber is considered out of scope. Here is a simple version of my code:

viewController.m

```
NSNumber *mean;
[statistics calculateMean:mean];
NSLog(@"%@ is the mean", mean);
//^on this line I get the error: "Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”."
//and when I hover over object it says "out of scope".
```

statistics.m

```
+ (void)calculateMean:(NSNumber*)MeanEst
{
    MeanEst = [stepFunc meanOfArray:sub_values]; 
    //meanOfArray returns an NSNumber*
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I am working on porting matlab code to objective-c. The matlab code is code that I did not write and I will not really be using this objective-c code. it is a project for someone else. So I am trying to write it in a way that is as similar to the matlab code as possible. In the matlab code there is a function defined as "function [mean_est, sig] = mean_est(candEventTimes)". Since I can't return two objects, I was hoping to pass them in as pointers and accomplish essentially the same thing.

Comment: you will need to retain the mean object. As it is an auto-released one. or you can use NSNumber *mean = [[stepFunc meanOfArray:sub_values] retain]; use it and release it after use.

Comment: Did you declare a property and a synthesizer for the NSNumber ?

Comment: Your NSNumber object is probably getting released somewhere. Track it down. (May be auto released)

Comment: has Ravin said you need to declare @property retained.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is the point of the parameter at all? Also what are stepFunc and sub_values, since you made this a class method it doesn't make much sense. My guess is you aren't sure what you are doing, no offense.

Comment: @Ravin I tried to add retain like this: meanEst = [stepFunc meanOfArray:sub_values];... I would rather not make it a property. I am able to do this similarly with NSMutableArrays.. are NSNumbers much different?

Comment: @exolaris - The names you use in your code are at confusing, can you post the complete code or at least explain what `statistics` and `stepFunc` are?

Comment: statistics and stepFunc are both classes. I was unaware of the naming convention that classes should be capitalized. sorry.

Comment: @exolaris: as sch already said: we need statistics and stepFunc. And please use small-caps first letter for name of a parameter (MeanEst should be meanEst). It's not really an error but code gets more readable and possibility for errors is smaller that way.

Comment: @exolaris - You can write more that one function (method) in a class, you don't need a class for every method.

Comment: @exolaris What are the 2 things you are trying to return in this one function? Could it simply be 2 values that could be returned in 2 separate methods?

Comment: @Lucas unfortunately no, they are calculated using the same algorithm so I would have to do the same thing twice if I split it into two methods.

Comment: @exolaris How exactly was your code above going to be useful then? If you need 2 values from something, then an NSNumber isn't going to accomplish that since it only holds 1 number. To be honest, we need to know what these 2 things are or how they are related so we can figure out what the right approach could be.

Comment: @exolaris: you can always create an object holding two values and returning if from you function (method). Much better than calling a method with parameters by reference.

Comment: @rokjarc That is what I have decided to do. It seems like my best option. Thanks for the reassurance.

Comment: Your `calculateMean` method is declared as a class method and doesn't have access to any instance variables.  Unless `subFunc` and `sub_values` are some sort of static values you will have trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Since NSNumber is not a primitive type you have to initialize it first.

```
NSNumber *mean = [NSNumber initWithFloat:0.0f];
[statistics calculateMean:mean];
```

Now you should be able to access the mean value properly. And also do check the meanOfArray method, whether it really returns a NSNumber object.

Comment: This won't produce the result @exolaris is looking for. After the call to `calculateMean`, the value of `mean` will remain unchanged: `0.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the pointer to pointer

```
NSNumber *mean;
[statistics calculateMean:&mean];
NSLog(@"%@ is the mean", mean);
```

and

```
+ (void)calculateMean:(NSNumber **)MeanEst
{
    *MeanEst = [stepFunc meanOfArray:sub_values]; 
    //meanOfArray returns an NSNumber*
}
```

Comment: This is I believe what the asker is trying to accomplish, however it should be noted that this is generally bad style when not necessary (which it's probably not in this case).

Comment: @Lucas what would be better style (I don't mean for that to sound rude I'm just curious). I don't understand why I can do this easily with NSMutableArrays but not with NSNumbers.. they are both objects.

Comment: @exolaris - Check my answer, I think he want to say that you can return the value from the method instead of using pointers to modify its value. Concerning arrays, you are not modifying the array itself when yo pass it as a parameter, you are just modifying its content.

Comment: @exolaris I mean you usually don't pass an object by reference in Obj-C because it's usually not needed. Perhaps if I better understood what your end goal was, I could explain a better option.

Comment: @Lucas -- If you don't pass an object by reference, how *do* you pass it??  I think what you mean is that you don't usually pass a *pointer* by reference.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry, I guess my wording isn't clear. Obj-C objects are already pointers, what I'm saying is you don't want to pass a pointer to an object (which is already a pointer, so it would be a pointer to a pointer).

Comment: @Lucas -- No, Objective-C objects are NOT pointers.  Core Foundation has "object references" which are basically typecast pointers (so that you never use the explicit `*`), but Cocoa objects use regular `*`-denoted pointers.  Pointers (or Core Foundation references) are what you *always* pass in Objective-C, except when passing "primitives" -- int, float, char, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry, you're right, I'm really not saying this correctly at all. All Obj-C objects require you to create a pointer to the object (NSString *). I'm contradicting myself :)